# GraphQL custom scalar type doesn't work in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, java-17, spring-graphql

I've configured GraphQL in spring boot application which uses `java 17`.
To start application you need `gradle bootRun`.

To try `GrapqQL` request you can use `curl`:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8085/graphql \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"query":"query {\n  bookById(id: \"book-1\"){\n    id\n    name\n    pageCount\n    productionDate\n    authors {\n      id\n      firstName\n      lastName\n    }\n  }\n}"}'
```

The current configuration doesn't use custom type `LocalDate` and no date formatting with pattern`"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

The GraphQL configuration `schema.graphqls`

```
type Query {
    bookById(id: ID): Book
}

type Book {
    id: ID
    name: String
    pageCount: Int
    authors: [Author]!
    productionDate: String
#    productionDate: LocalDate
}

type Author {
    id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
}
```

requires `productionDate: LocalDate` (in the line 10). The custom `java` configuration is managed in the `ScalarConfiguration.java` following [spring-boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.1.0-RC1/reference/html),

```
package com.graphqljava.tutorial.bookDetails;

import graphql.language.StringValue;
import graphql.schema.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.GraphQlSourceBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.RuntimeWiringConfigurer;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class ScalarConfiguration {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

    @Bean
    public GraphQLScalarType dateScalar() {
        return GraphQLScalarType.newScalar()
                .name("LocalDate")
                .description("Java 8 LocalDate as scalar.")
                .coercing(new Coercing<Object, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public String serialize(final Object dataFetcherResult) {
                        if (dataFetcherResult instanceof LocalDate) {
                            return formatter.format((LocalDate) dataFetcherResult);
                        } else {
                            throw new CoercingSerializeException("Expected a LocalDate object.");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public LocalDate parseValue(final Object input) {
                        try {
                            if (input instanceof String) {
                                return LocalDate.parse((String) input, formatter);
                            } else {
                                throw new CoercingParseValueException("Expected a String");
                            }
                        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                            throw new CoercingParseValueException(String.format("Not a valid date: '%s'.", input), e
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public LocalDate parseLiteral(final Object input) {
                        if (input instanceof StringValue) {
                            try {
                                return LocalDate.parse(((StringValue) input).getValue(), formatter);
                            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                                throw new CoercingParseLiteralException(e);
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new CoercingParseLiteralException("Expected a StringValue.");
                        }
                    }
                }).build();
    }

    // https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.1.0-RC1/reference/html/#execution-graphqlsource-runtimewiring-configurer
    @Bean
    RuntimeWiringConfigurer runtimeWiringConfigurer() {
        GraphQLScalarType scalarType = dateScalar();
        return wiringBuilder -> wiringBuilder.scalar(scalarType);
    }

/*
    // https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.1.0-RC1/reference/html/#execution-graphqlsource
    @Bean
    public GraphQlSourceBuilderCustomizer sourceBuilderCustomizer() {
        GraphQLScalarType scalarType = dateScalar();
        return (builder) ->
                builder.configureGraphQl(graphQlBuilder ->
                        graphQlBuilder.executionIdProvider((query, operationName, context) -> null));
    }
*/

}
```

so `runtimeWiringConfigurer` loads correctly, but `LocalDate` doesn't work in my `schema.graphqls` and I'm looking for help and solution with described issue.

### P.S.

- [The git source is here](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/graphql-tutorials).
- I've detected there similar questions, but their answers didn't help me properly. In current question I've provided git java project which can be fixed to make working it with `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue can be resolved declaring correspond scalar type in `graphqls` file `scalar LocalDate`.

So `schema.graphqls` looks like:

```
scalar LocalDate

type Query {
    bookById(id: ID): Book
}

type Book {
    id: ID
    name: String
    pageCount: Int
    authors: [Author]!
    productionDate: LocalDate
}

type Author {
    id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
}
```

The fix is [published to the git](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/stackoverflow-questions/blob/master/graphql-tutorials/src/main/resources/graphql/schema.graphqls) also.